# How to copy files from prevoius non-msi installation?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm changing my installer from NSIS to MSI (using Wix) and I need to copy configuration files from the old installation to the new one in case of upgrade.

Before actually installing the new version I need to uninstall the old one by executing its uninstaller.

So I ended up with a set of custom actions: first I stop the application if it's running; then I copy the configuration files to `[TempFolder]`; then I start the uninstaller of the old application; after that I let the MSI do its job and as a final step I've put a bunch of `<CopyFile>` to copy from the `[TempFolder]` to the installation folder.

The problem is that Microsoft Installer 5 (the one of Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2) seems to check for the file existence before starting my custom actions and then it will not copy them. It is working fine with previous Windows Installer version, up to 4.5.

Is there a way to enforce the check after my custom actions? Or there is a better way to do all the steps I outlined?

Answer (score 1):

MoveFiles action comes before InstallFiles. Maybe the files are copied correctly but the MSI overwrites them. Please generate a log file for more details.

Comment: No, the problem is that the action never executes: the file are not there. The only way to have it work is by creating fake files in the temporary folder before starting the installer. My guess is that InstallValidate action check for the existence of files and if not found it will skip the copy. But this only happens with msi 5, because with msi 4.5 it works perfectly

Comment: When is the custom action that copies the files to temp scheduled? Any custom action that affect costing should be sequenced before the CostInitialize action.

Comment: I can't schedule it before CostInitialize, because it's a deferred action (I need it to run with elevated privileges)

Comment: Then you will have to use a custom action instead of a Copy operation.

Comment: Do you mean I need a custom action also to copy files from temp folder to installation folder?